# Python: How to add a custom function to a pre-existing object?

Tags: python, function, class, object, methods

Is it possible to add your own custom function to an already existing object?

For example, the 'string' datatype has no built-in `reverse()` function unlike in a `list`, is there a way to add a reverse function such that if I have a string variable `var`, `var.reverse()` returns the string in reverse?

One way I think this would work is if I create a `class CustomString` that has the same properties as a string but with an additional defined reverse function, is this possible? (I'm not yet familiar with Python OOP)

Or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: What you're describing is referred to as "monkey patching", but you can't use it on string objects; subclassing is your best option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using inheritance:

```
class new_string(str):
    def reverse(self):
        blah

s = new_string('hello')
s.reverse()
```

EDIT: Does your code look like this:

```
>>> class S(str):
...     def reverse(self):
...         return self.__str__()[::-1]
... 
>>> s = S('hello')
>>> s.reverse()
'olleh'
```

Comment: Thanks :) but I have another question, how do I save the changes done? as in [here](http://pastebin.com/Ct9Dd5CZ)

Comment: nope, it looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/Ct9Dd5CZ)

Can you please tell me what's wrong? :)
I want `reverse()` to be a process that reverses the string itself instead of returning a copy of the string in reverse.

Comment: That should really be opened as a new question

Comment: Alright, I see, thanks :)
Gonna ask this as a new question after the post limit expires.

Comment: @DarkPotatoKing Python strings are immutable so I'm not really sure you'll be able to accomplish what you want to.